# iOS Can't play .mov file with H.263 codec using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using an `AVPlayerLayer` to display video in my iOS app.

I'm able to play the video as intended with most files, for example `.mov`-files with `HEVC` and `AAC` codecs, as well as `.mp4`-files with `H.264` and `AAC` codecs.

However, I noticed that **my player does not play when using a `.mov`-file with `H.263` and `AMR Narrowband` codecs**. I get no error when initializing my `AVPlayerLayer`/`AVPlayer`/`AVPlayerItems` with this type of video file although when I try to play nothing is rendered in the `AVPlayerLayer` and no sound is played either.

Also, note that the default image-library app on my iPhone 12 Pro iOS 15 is able to play the `.mov` with  `H.263` codec, and if I convert it to `.mp4` from `.mov` (obtaining `H.264` with `AAC`) it works as well so it is not corrupted.

I'm basically looking for any information about why this is happening, as **I would like to detect when video-files aren't able to be played using AVPlayer**. So far all I've found is to check `AVAsset.isPlayable`, which returns `true` when called with the `H.263` `.mov` video file asset even though it obviously cannot be played.

**Edit**:
[Here is a link to the video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqbfjax2gr4pdte/bad_video.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Usually iPhone only supports H.264 and H.265, certainly for HLS stream videos. Can you share a link to your video to help people investigate?

Comment: I added the video now, good suggestion